# IE6 and IE7 CSS help

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

working on a site for a client (demo page here, still under construction: http://www.wmaxwell.com/newsite.html ). The 4 tabs line up fine in FF 3.6, IE8 and Chrome, but when I checked it out (using Virtual PC) with IE6 and IE7, the tabs are all crooked. Can anyone using IE6 or IE7 confirm this for me, and can anyone give me some help with the css? Obviously it's a bug in their renderer, but I don't know how to fix it (I would supply a custom stylesheet for those browsers using conditional comments).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:
li { 
    display:inline;
}

Also, you can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to check out different browsers without using a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Thanks for the display:inline! So simple yet so what I needed; it worked like a charm! and thanks for IETester as well; much better than a VirtualPC for sure!

Gaby: I didn't try yours, but I'm sure that it'd probably work as well.

I guess I still have lots to learn about CSS! :)